# How can I make a variable n zeros?

Tags: python

So I want to create something like

`myvariable = n * 0`

but I want zeros to repeat N times back to back (not on different lines)
the thing i need to do: 00000

How can I do this?

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify your intent (give examples of desired output).

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> n = 5
>>> myvariable = n * '0'
>>> print(myvariable)
00000
```

Comment: Oh I didn't know that worked, i thought it would just do an operation with zero but I forgot to take zero as a string. Would the result of this be a string or an integer?

Comment: @QueensGambyte a string obviously, an integer cannot have leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

if you use multiply operator with a string in python, It repeats your string n times.

For example :

```
N = 3
yourString = "python"
```

when you use this code:

```
print(N * yourString)
```

it will return "python" three times:

Output: **pythonpythonpython**